# package from IP arrives at certain port => open portrange to IP for x seconds

Tags: iptables, ip, firewall

I have been toiling with an issue on iptables:

I am trying to make a portrange open to a specific IP for x seconds/minutes as a result of a single packet being sent to a specific port.

Not exactly for portknocking but same principle - however I just can't make it work. Here is what I have done so far - I may have completely misunderstood something as I only just started working with firewalls and especially iptables.

The code:

```
#########       UPnP        ###########

#Opens up for all udp ports on local network - not so good.
#-A INPUT -s 10.10.10.254/24 -i eno1 -p udp -m udp -j ACCEPT

#Opens for the needed ports for syncthing but still too many
#-A INPUT -s 10.10.10.254/24 -i eno1 -p udp --match multiport --dports 40000:65000 -j ACCEPT

#allows for related ports to be opened along with ones already established. Does not work
-A INPUT -s 10.10.10.254/24 -i eno1 -p udp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

###### Opening op selected portrange when udp package is received on port 1900 for x seconds

#Creating chain STATE0-1

-N STATE0
-A INPUT -j STATE0

#Opening and receiving package from port 1900
-A STATE0 -s 10.10.10.254/24 -i eno1 -m state --state NEW -p udp -m udp --dport 1900 -m recent --name UPnPpacket --set -j ACCEPT
-A STATE0 -j DROP

-N STATE1

#Looking at recent with name UPnPpacket and if it exists open ports 40000:65000 for 10 seconds 
###
#-A STATE1 -s 10.10.10.254/24 -i eno1 -m state --state NEW -p udp --match multiport --dports 40000:65000 -m recent --rcheck --seconds 10 --name UPnPpacket -j ACCEPT 
###
#trying this instead
-A STATE1 -m recent --name UPnPpacket --remove
-A STATE1 -s 10.10.10.254/24 -i eno1 -p udp --match multiport --dports 40000:65000 -j ACCEPT
-A STATE1 -j STATE0
```

As you can see I am attempting to make UPnP work with arch linux... Not an easy task I might add :-)

Cheers,

------------##########-----------

UPDATE:

```
    ########################################
#########       UPnP        ###########

#allows for related ports to be opened along with ones already established. Does not work on its own
-A INPUT -s 10.10.10.254/24 -i eno1 -p udp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#Open up for the multicast discovery (THESE SHOULD BE DELETED ONE BY ONE TO TEST WHICH ARE NEEDED)
-A INPUT -i eno1 -d 224.0.0.0/8 -p igmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eno1 -s 0.0.0.0/32 -d 224.0.0.1/32 -p igmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p igmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Upon a udp package being received on port 1900 from the local subnet
# the port range 40000:65000 is opened for 30 seconds.

#0 Create chain and give packages received name
-N INTO-PHASE2

#3 Take all packages arriving in chain INTO-PHASE2 and rename them from PHASE1 to PHASE 2 and log the event
-A INTO-PHASE2 -m recent --name PHASE1 --remove
-A INTO-PHASE2 -m recent --name PHASE2 --set
-A INTO-PHASE2 -j LOG --log-prefix "INTO PHASE2: "

#1 Name incoming packages
-A INPUT -s 10.10.10.254/24 -p udp -m recent --update --name PHASE1

#1 Name packages from port 1900 from local subnet and name it PHASE1
-A INPUT -s 10.10.10.254/24 -i eno1 -p udp -m udp --dport 1900 -m recent --set --name PHASE1 -j INTO-PHASE2

# Check for whether a package received on portrange has a sender with the same IP as sender of package PHASE1, if so, pass package into the INTO-PHASE2 chain.
-A INPUT -s 10.10.10.254/24 -p udp --match multiport --dports 30000:65000 -m recent --rcheck --name PHASE1 -j ACCEPT

# Check packages arriving at portrange from local subnet to see if they have the name "PHASE2" - they they do and they are recent open accepting all packages the portrange for 30 seconds
-A INPUT -s 10.10.10.254/24 -p udp --match multiport --dports 30000:65000 -m recent --rcheck --seconds 30 --name PHASE2 -j ACCEPT

#test
#-A INPUT -s 10.10.10.254/24 -p udp --match multiport --dports 30000:65000 -j ACCEPT

#############
```

I do not know what the issue is but the package is received and accepted at 1900 udp however it refuses to open op the portrange....

Answer (score 0):

This is a ruleset that may do what you want. (Modified from a similar rule used to allow knocking on an external port.

```
-A INPUT -p udp --dport 30000:65000   -m recent --rcheck --seconds 60 --name UPnP          -j ACCEPT'
-A INPUT -p upd --dport 1899 -m recent                       --name UPnP --remove -j DROP
-A INPUT -p udp --dport 1900 -m recent                       --name UPnP --set    -j DROP
-A INPUT -p udp --dport 1901 -m recent                       --name UPnP --remove -j DROP
```

You may be better with a real UPnP daemon such as `miniupnpd`.  It will manage the firewall in a more appropriate way.  Some daemons can be configured to limit the open ports to the requesting client rather than all hosts on the network.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Sadly this ruleset does not work :-/ 
I have been looking at miniupnpc - it is possibly a viable solution but I cannot figure out how to create a simple functioning configuration for it and what I need to change in iptables to get it to work .... :-S